# MFC: Make dialog always above A SMALL SET of other dialogs

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, z-order

Google-ing yields results on how to make a dialog "always on top" of everything.  This is not what I want, though.

Say I have a huge amount of dialogs.  Within this pile of dialogs, consider 3 of them -- A, B and C.

I want C to always be on top of A and B, but not the rest of the pile.  In other words, if C is active, then it should be on top, otherwise it will be below another active dialog, except for when it involves A and B.

And by the way, A and B can never appear at the same time.

With that, the only way I've managed to do it is by destroying C every time, and then re-create it with a new parent (A or B, depending who is visible).  I've learned that once child dialogs are created, the ownership cannot be transferred, hence the need to destroy.

I cannot afford to keep destroying it (long story to it).

Any other way to achieve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> With that, the only way I've managed to do it is by destroying C every time, and then re-create it with a new parent (A or B, depending who is visible).

If you have the handle to C's window in A or B, how about sending a user-defined message to C, when ever you want to set C as TopMost ?

Comment: I am new to MFC, so can you please elaborate on the "user-defined message" part?  I roughly understand that I can send my on ON_? messages, but upon receiving it, what can I do with it?

I've read somewhere in MSDN that parenting (or is it ownership) can only be decided during Create() like I mentioned above -- if I can do something about it from receiving a message, then the statement in the documentation is no longer true?